# Angular 2 [src] Show different images

Tags: angular

I make a query with HTTP POST and return the data.

I want to show different images because there is more than one data in a list.

How can I do it ?

```html
<ion-list>
  <ion-list-header>FİRMALARIM</ion-list-header>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let firma of uyeninFirmalari">
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img [src]="firmaProfil[firma.firma_profil_foto]">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>{{ firma.firma_adi }}</h2>
    <!-- <p></p> -->
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

My .ts,

```html
export class HomePage {

imageUrl:string="http://www.elli2.com/xxx/xxxx/firma_profil/";
profilTanimla:string;
dizi:any;
  constructor(public http: Http, public navCtrl: NavController, public authservice:AuthService, public app:App) {
     this.dizi = this.authservice.sayfalaraGonder();
     this.uye_adi=this.dizi.uye_adi;
     this.uye_id=this.dizi.uye_id;
     this.uyeFirmalar(); // My data list in view
    }
  firmaProfil(firma_profil:string){
   this.imageUrl+firma_profil; 
  }
```

```
uyeFirmalar(){ 
    let url:string="elli2.com/mobil/uyeFirmalari";; 
    var uye_id = JSON.stringify({uye_id:this.uye_id}); 
    this.http.post(url,uye_id).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(da‌​ta=>{ 
        this.uyeninFirmalari=data; 
        this.firmaProfil=data.firma_profil; 
    }); 
}
```

What do you recommend ?

Comment: Where do you fill `uyeninFirmalari`? Can you please share all the relevant code?

Comment: uyeFirmalar(){
    let url:string="http://www.elli2.com/mobil/uyeFirmalari";
    var uye_id = JSON.stringify({uye_id:this.uye_id});
    this.http.post(url,uye_id).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
      this.uyeninFirmalari=data;
    });
  }   this code

Comment: Assuming `+` is `=` at the end, what does your `data` look like? Is it an array?

Comment: Yes, it's an array

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Picture appears and does not appear in the list. Do I need to call a function in Construct?

Comment: Change firmaProfil[firma.firma_profil_foto] to firmaProfil(firma.firma_profil_foto) on the img tag.